# Where is the object of "into" in "a sauce for dipping pieces of food into"?

Tags: prepositions, parsing, objects

[Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions) doesn't mark "*into*" as a preposition that can be used intransitively, i. e. "*into*" must always have an object.

Here are my three phrases where "*a thick cold sauce*" is the object of "*into*":
**(1)** *to dip pieces of food into a thick cold sauce*
**(2)** *a thick cold sauce to dip pieces of food into* - (the infinitive clause is relative here)
**(3)** *a thick cold sauce (that) you could dip pieces of food into* - (the that-clause is relative here)

one of the meanings of "dip" from [macmillandictionary.com](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dip_2#dip_2__6):
**(4a)** *a thick cold sauce for dipping pieces of food **into** before eating them*
my variant:
**(4b)** *a thick cold sauce for dipping pieces of food **into it** before eating them*

Since a "*for + ing-clause*" construction can't be relative, then (4a) must be ungrammatical and only (4b) correct.

How is it possible that "*into*" in (4a) doesn't have an object?

Comment: Since the dictionary gives 4a and _not_ 4b, obviously 4a is the correct one. "For dipping pieces of food into" is a phrase describing the purpose of the sauce.

Comment: @KateBunting "_Since the dictionary gives 4a and not 4b, obviously 4a is the correct one_." - obviously I understand this. Could you explain to me please how your comment can help to deal with the issue?

Comment: I was commenting on your assertion that "4a must be ungrammatical and 4b correct"!

Comment: @KateBunting At the end of the original post I wrote the question "_How is it possible that "into" in (4a) doesn't have an object_?" This question can only mean that I understand that (4a) is correct because it's from the dictionary!

Comment: We're talking about dipping food _into_ the sauce, aren't we? As a native speaker I'm not aware of the rule you refer to, I just know that we say _a useful pot to keep things in_ (to quote A.A. Milne) and not _a pot to keep things in it_.

Comment: @KateBunting "_Since the dictionary gives 4a and not 4b, obviously 4a is the correct one._" - maybe I incorrectly translated this into my native language. The way I understood it is 4a is correct. But maybe your sentence means 4a is **the only** correct variant, i.e. 4b is incorrect... Is 4b correct?

Comment: 4b is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The concept at work here is called **preposition stranding**. In canonical order, the object of a transitive preposition follows it. But in several constructions, this is not the case:

- I am looking at photos. (canonical order)
- Which photos are you looking at? (interrogative)
- the photos I am looking at (relative)
- the photos at which I am looking (relative with whole prepositional phrase fronted—rather formal)
- some photos to look at (infinitival relative)
- some photos at which to look (infinitival relative: fronted)
- the photos have been looked at (prepositional passive)

You are asking about another construction, one that might be called an **adnominal participial purpose clause**. Preposition stranding is allowed here too. An example is

- some photos for looking at

It is similar in meaning to an infinitival relative.

Comment: By analogy with infinitival relative clauses, can we put "_which_" in front: "_some photos at which for looking_"? Thanks.

Comment: No. That's why it's not a relative clause.